# ruby just dies on "ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

this is a follow up to my other question regarding unicorn. following problem:
i'm using ruby 1.8.7, rails 3.0, pg gem (0.13.0).

when i start the rails console in production mode, i can query records etc, so the
database connection and the pgsql adapter works. i can disconnect the AR connection via `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!`, but as soon as i try to reconnect using `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`, ruby just dies. no error, no log output, no seg fault, it just quits (with status 1). i tried setting the `host` in my database.yml to the postgres unix socket, as well as to `127.0.0.1`, doesn't change a thing. what could be the problem, or what can i do to get to the root of this? i'm not sure how to debug this, with absolutely no output or error message.

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem (more or less) by downgrading `pg` to version 0.11.0. this works for me for now. cost me 1 and a 1/2 days ...

Comment: Did you [open a bug against the `pg` gem](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issues)? This sounds like a pretty serious problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you closing explicitely the connection to the database ? Rails/AR handles the connection pool for you. The rack middleware is supposed to release connections at the end of the request processing.

Comment: that's just the test case to demonstrate the issue, i need to close and reopen the connection for unicorn (using before and after fork hooks)

Comment: If it can help, I usually build configurations for Unicorn based on GitHub's one : https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn